# Aligning elements adjacent to sortable handle in Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list of items (each with a draggable handle) and I'm trying to align some elements within each item: a title, link, and some descriptive text. The items are adjacent to a left-floated div (the "handle" you see on the left). Unfortunately, there is a large gap between the title and the link:

[image: There's a gap between the title and the link]

(http://www.bootply.com/101604)

Here's a mock-up I made in an image editing program that illustrates what I'm trying to achieve (no large gap between the title and the link):

[image: Here's the ideal layout--without the gap]

I know it has something to do with the `.handle` div which is floated left and has a specified width and height, but I can't quite figure it out. When I remove the `.handle`, everything lines up fine without the awkward gap. I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I'm struggling to find an answer. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these properties to your existing classes:

```
.itemSubContainer {
  overflow:hidden;
}
.handle {
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

To help clear your floated elemets, because your itemSubContainer class doesn't know about the containing elements because they are floated and taken out of the flow.

Comment: Thanks, 1337! Here's a fixed version using your suggestions: http://www.bootply.com/101614

Comment: Happy to help, it was the easiest and simplest solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`Media Object`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media) implementation given in Bootstrap. It includes a left-floated element with multiple text elements on its right.

```
<div class="media">
  <a class="pull-left" href="#">
    <img class="media-object" src="..." alt="...">
  </a>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.row` itself is also floating left and each `.row` clears the float. Instead of floating `.handle`, use `position: absolute` so the handle doesn't interfere with the rest of the content.

Note that there's also a 10px margin on `h4` that you may wish to adjust.

[image]